# Knockout AMD & Postal.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, amd, knockout-components

I'm using knockout components and postal.js for the communication between the components.

I have registered two components, A and B. When the page loads, I want A to send a message to B. I have this:

```
define(['postal',''text!./templateA.html''], function (postal, html) {
    function ComponentA() {
        postal.publish({
            channel: "channel1",
            topic: "topic1",
            data: "Hello!"
        });
    }    
    return { viewModel: ComponentA, template: html };
}
```

...

```
define(['postal',''text!./templateB.html''], function (postal, html) {
    function ComponentB() {
        postal.subscribe({
            channel: "channel1",
            topic: "topic1",
            callback: doSomething
        });
    }
    return { viewModel: ComponentB, template: html };
}
```

The problem is that sometimes component A sends the message before component B is loaded, and therefore, ready to receive the message. So the message is lost and the action in component B is not executed.

**EDIT:**

What's the best way to control the order how components are loaded?

Comment: As became clear from your comment to my initial answer, it now seems your actual question boils down to *how* to guarantee loading order with AMD and ko-components. I've deleted my answer (it's no longer relevant), but I do suggest you expand your question's code a wee bit into a [mcve], so we can see how you bootstrap your application and components currently.

Comment: Possibly relevant [Knock Me Out - Using KO’s Native PubSub for Decoupled Synchronization](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/using-ko-native-pubsub.html)

Comment: As @Tomalak suggest, if you're already using knockout then knockout-postbox could be handy. Give it a try https://github.com/rniemeyer/knockout-postbox